# Scroll position in inner div on page after return (reload or back in history)

Tags: css, html, scroll, back, browser-history

I have problem with scrolling in page. I have scrollable page and inner another scrollable DIV on page where is long list of links. And if I go to linked page from this list and want go back (normal back button in browser) IE and Chrome take me to top of the list (top of inner DIV) but Firefox return exact original scroll position in this list. 
Is there any solution to get the original scroll position in IE and Chrome?

Comment: You could manually save scrollTops values at page unload, storing then restoring them at page load. But that would be quite messy, and could lead to strange behaviour when mixed up with the browser own restore-scroll system.

Comment: Did you ever find a good solution?